# How can I make a PSU power a lightbulb?

Tags: power-supply, power, led, case-mods

I'm making a steampunk PC chassis and I'd like to have the PC be able to light up lights like these [Edison Vintage Bulbs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GI12LL0):

[image]

Is there a way to hook lights or anything else like that to a PSU or the LED light connectors on a Phanteks case or something?

Comment: No... Basic rules of electricity here. Your power supply takes 110-240vAC and converts it to 12, 5, 3.3, and maybe other DC voltages at very precise levels, it can't power standard 120vAC 60w light bulbs, that is what the power socket in the wall is for.

Answer (score 3):

No. The bulbs you linked to are incandescent bulbs that require mains voltage (110-120 VAC in the United States). You'll only get DC voltages from a computer power supply.

You ought to look into "LED filament bulbs", which actually use thin, flexible LEDs to achieve the same look as those Edison bulbs. E.g., [these LED bulbs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FO79VSA) will run on just 12 VDC.

Comment: But how will he get this bulb powered from the PSU? Are there adapters from a PSU output to a DC light bulb socket?

Comment: You can abuse molex or floppy connectors in wild and wonderful ways

Comment: @JourneymanGeek How is this question not applicable? I'm asking how to run filament lights with computer hardware. It says in the help center: **And is not about** _electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer_ I've seen other people do it so I know it's possible. I'm not asking about lights and I said "or anything like that" because I didn't mean those lights specifically.  Also P Fitz had an applicable answer so others might as well...

Comment: interface, dosen't necessarily mean bodge.  Following your arguement, we can probably allow questions on interfacing toasters and bathtubs with your PC as well.